# Drawing Area not showing up (not aligning correctly?)

Tags: java, swing

I am wondering why the drawing area I have created is not showing up in my second panel. I have checked their locations uses getX and getY (250, 0, which is I am assuming the correct area for it to be since that would be the top left of the second panel), but I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong. I'm assuming this is a problem with some fundamental learning aspect of this that I do not have right, but cannot seem to figure out what the issue is. If you could explain to me what is going wrong and the proper direction as to where I would go about fixing it, that would be appreciated. I do have the drawing area working when I have it standalone; the issue is that I cannot get it to appear when working with other GUI components.

Thank you ^^

Code:
package Drawing;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


public class DrawingApp extends JFrame{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(1, 2);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final DrawingComponent drawingArea = new DrawingComponent();
    drawingArea.setSize(600, 250);
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
    JSlider greSlider = new JSlider();
    JSlider bluSlider = new JSlider();
    JSlider redSlider = new JSlider();
    Point leftLocation = new Point(0, 0);
    Point rightLocation = new Point(250, 0);

    JLabel greLabel = new JLabel("Green");
    JLabel bluLabel = new JLabel("Blue");
    JLabel redLabel = new JLabel("Red");

    rightPanel.setLocation(rightLocation);
    drawingArea.setLocation(rightLocation);
   // JButton button = new JButton("Hello");

    leftPanel.setSize(250, 600);
    //leftPanel.setLocation(leftLocation);
    leftPanel.setBorder((BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black)));

    rightPanel.setSize(250, 600);
    //rightPanel.setLocation(rightLocation);
    rightPanel.setBorder((BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green)));

    leftPanel.add(greLabel);
    leftPanel.add(greSlider);
    leftPanel.add(bluLabel);
    leftPanel.add(bluSlider);
    leftPanel.add(redLabel);
    leftPanel.add(redSlider);
    rightPanel.add(drawingArea);
    frame.add(leftPanel);
    frame.add(rightPanel);
    //rightPanel.add(button);
    frame.setSize(500, 600);
    frame.setLayout(grid);





    leftPanel.setVisible(true);
    rightPanel.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    class SlideClickListener implements ChangeListener
    {

        ChangeListener slideListener = new ChangeListener(){

         @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
            if(e.getSource() == greSlider){

            }
        }
    };


        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supportedyet.");    
        }
    }

    class MouseClickListener implements MouseListener
    {  
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
        {  
           int x = event.getX();
           int y = event.getY();
           System.out.println(x + " " + y);
           drawingArea.drawPoints(x,y);
        }
        // Do­nothing methods
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
     }

    MouseListener listener = new MouseClickListener();
    drawingArea.addMouseListener(listener);


}

}
```

I can include the DrawingComponent class if needed, but assuming that it isn't since I know for sure that the class is working.

Comment: So, where's `DrawingComponent`? Going to be hard to diagnose the issue without it

Comment: In the future post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm assuming this is a problem with some fundamental learning aspect of this that I do not have right,

You don't appear to understand how layout managers work:

```
leftPanel.setSize(250, 600);
//leftPanel.setLocation(leftLocation);
rightPanel.setSize(250, 600);
//rightPanel.setLocation(rightLocation);
```

None of those statements will do anything. It is the job of the layout manager to determine the size and location of components added to the panel. In your case you are trying to use a `GridLayout`. So the components added to the grid will be given a size AFTER the decorations of the frame are taken into consideration. So even though the frame may be (500, 600), the space available to the panel will be less (because you need to account for the title bar and borders of the frame).

Also, you should assign the layout manager to the panel BEFORE you add components to the panel.

```
leftPanel.setVisible(true);
rightPanel.setVisible(true);
```

Swing components (except top level containers like JFrame, JDialog) are visible by default so the above code does nothing.

> I can include the DrawingComponent class if needed,

Until a problem is solved you don't know what is or isn't relative to the problem. My guess is the your `DrawingComponent` is the problem. Again, the default layout manager of a JPanel is the `FlowLayout` which respects the preferred size of any component added to it. I'm guessing your `DrawingPanel` doesn't implement the `getPreferredSize()` method to the preferred size is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

I would suggest you also look at the `Layout Managers` section of the tutorial for layout basics and working examples.